# SD card keeps ejecting itself

Tags: sd-card

I have a problem with a micro SD card (samsung EVO 32Go) : 
Each time I insert it in my computer, it ejects itself when I want to read a file, delete a file or edit the card in any way (formatting, etc). It is then often "re-detected" by the OS.

I tried with several adapters
I tried to format or to delete the partition (with gparted and fdisk to be sure) but it ejects itself and nothing changes.

I also tried with a windows 7 OS, same results.

Note : it is a microSD => no physical lock
the card only has one partition which takes the whole disk space

Any idea?

EDIT : 
If it can be useful, this card was used on an android device.

If I try to delete the partition or create a new partition table through gparted, it can manage to do it (success message displayed) but in reality, nothing changes on the device.

Comment: In gparted, did you try to create a new partition table? `Device > Create Partition Table... > msdos > Apply`

Comment: I just tried it. I get errors because of the ejection but, after several tries, it **seems** to work. The problem is : after re-mounting the device, I see no change on it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to CHKDSK. Run CHKDSK followed by drive letter, colon and /FAT at the command prompt to fix any issues out there.